# Are BOOTAPP from the bcdedit /create /? command related in description of the /application parameter and the Boot subsystem in the Microsoft linker?

Tags: c++, windows, osdev

I once watched the link command with the /? parameter and I saw the BOOT subsystem, which is not in Visual Studio. I went to look for information about the subsystem, but I didn't find it. I recently executed the bcdedit /create /? command and saw that the description of the /application parameter indicates that there may be a BOOTAPP. I didn't find any information on the Internet. Is the BOOT subsystem connected to the Windows loader, how do I create an application for the Windows loader in C++ and can I use this for osdev?

I tried to find answers to the questions on my own, compiled a test program, but I didn't understand how to run it.